# Select a selection option based on text

Tags: javascript, dom

I need it in "modern DOM" if possible.

Here is the code.

```
<select name="skuAndSize" id="skuAndSize" class="ncss-btn fs16-sm ncss-base pb3-sm prl5-sm pt3-sm css-1rsed2n">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select Size</option>
  <option value="22348626:7" disabled="">US 7</option>
  <option value="22348625:7.5" disabled="">US 7.5</option>
  <option value="22348624:8" disabled="">US 8</option>
  <option value="22348621:8.5" disabled="">US 8.5</option>
  <option value="22348619:9" disabled="">US 9</option>
  <option value="22348623:9.5">US 9.5</option>
  <option value="22348618:10">US 10</option>
  <option value="22348622:10.5">US 10.5</option>
  <option value="22348635:11">US 11</option>
  <option value="22348634:11.5" disabled="">US 11.5</option>
  <option value="22348633:12">US 12</option>
  <option value="22348632:12.5" disabled="">US 12.5</option>
  <option value="22348631:13">US 13</option>
  <option value="22348630:14" disabled="">US 14</option>
  <option value="22348629:15" disabled="">US 15</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following but I need it for text and this does not work.

```
var val = 'US 10.5';    
document.querySelector('#skuAndSize [value="' + val + '"]').selected = true;
```

Please help, I need this in modern dom as I am using it in Swift (evaluateJavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

## Quick answer

You can set the value of a select by setting the property `value`:

```
document.querySelector('#skuAndSize').value = '22348622:10.5';
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

## Complete Example

```js
const tests = [4, 'Three', 2, '1'];
let i = 0;

window.setInterval(() => {
  const value = tests[i++ % tests.length];
  document.querySelector('select').value = value;
  document.querySelector('p').textContent = `Programatically set \´${value}\´ (type: ${typeof value})`;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>-</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and compare the `text` property of `<option>` to wanted value

```js
var val = 'US 10.5',
  options = document.querySelector('#skuAndSize').options,
  wantedOption = Array.from(options).find(o => o.text === val);
  
if (wantedOption) {
  wantedOption.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select name="skuAndSize" id="skuAndSize" class="ncss-btn fs16-sm ncss-base pb3-sm prl5-sm pt3-sm css-1rsed2n">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select Size</option>
  <option value="22348626:7" disabled="">US 7</option>
  <option value="22348625:7.5" disabled="">US 7.5</option>
  <option value="22348624:8" disabled="">US 8</option>
  <option value="22348621:8.5" disabled="">US 8.5</option>
  <option value="22348619:9" disabled="">US 9</option>
  <option value="22348623:9.5">US 9.5</option>
  <option value="22348618:10">US 10</option>
  <option value="22348622:10.5">US 10.5</option>
  <option value="22348635:11">US 11</option>
  <option value="22348634:11.5" disabled="">US 11.5</option>
  <option value="22348633:12">US 12</option>
  <option value="22348632:12.5" disabled="">US 12.5</option>
  <option value="22348631:13">US 13</option>
  <option value="22348630:14" disabled="">US 14</option>
  <option value="22348629:15" disabled="">US 15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is jquery version for your requirement.

```js
$('#skuAndSize').change(function(){

var text1 = 'US 10.5';
$("#skuAndSize option").filter(function() {
    
    return $(this).text() == text1; 
}).prop('selected', true);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="skuAndSize" id="skuAndSize" class="ncss-btn fs16-sm ncss-base pb3-sm prl5-sm pt3-sm css-1rsed2n">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select Size</option>
  <option value="22348626:7" disabled="">US 7</option>
  <option value="22348625:7.5" disabled="">US 7.5</option>
  <option value="22348624:8" disabled="">US 8</option>
  <option value="22348621:8.5" disabled="">US 8.5</option>
  <option value="22348619:9" disabled="">US 9</option>
  <option value="22348623:9.5">US 9.5</option>
  <option value="22348618:10">US 10</option>
  <option value="22348622:10.5">US 10.5</option>
  <option value="22348635:11">US 11</option>
  <option value="22348634:11.5" disabled="">US 11.5</option>
  <option value="22348633:12">US 12</option>
  <option value="22348632:12.5" disabled="">US 12.5</option>
  <option value="22348631:13">US 13</option>
  <option value="22348630:14" disabled="">US 14</option>
  <option value="22348629:15" disabled="">US 15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set selectedIndex with javascript

```js
const val = 'US 10.5';
const skuAndSize = document.getElementById ('skuAndSize');
skuAndSize.selectedIndex = [...skuAndSize.options].findIndex (option => option.text === val);
```

```html
<select name="skuAndSize" id="skuAndSize" class="ncss-btn fs16-sm ncss-base pb3-sm prl5-sm pt3-sm css-1rsed2n">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select Size</option>
  <option value="22348626:7" disabled="">US 7</option>
  <option value="22348625:7.5" disabled="">US 7.5</option>
  <option value="22348624:8" disabled="">US 8</option>
  <option value="22348621:8.5" disabled="">US 8.5</option>
  <option value="22348619:9" disabled="">US 9</option>
  <option value="22348623:9.5">US 9.5</option>
  <option value="22348618:10">US 10</option>
  <option value="22348622:10.5">US 10.5</option>
  <option value="22348635:11">US 11</option>
  <option value="22348634:11.5" disabled="">US 11.5</option>
  <option value="22348633:12">US 12</option>
  <option value="22348632:12.5" disabled="">US 12.5</option>
  <option value="22348631:13">US 13</option>
  <option value="22348630:14" disabled="">US 14</option>
  <option value="22348629:15" disabled="">US 15</option>
</select>
```